# How to determine the filesize with different encoding code?

Tags: utf-8, computer-science, utf-16

The Orchid Pavilion(兰亭集序) is well known as the top of “行书”in history of Chinese literature. The most fascinating sentence is "Well I know it is a lie to say that life and death is the same thing, and that longevity and early death make no difference Alas!"By counting the characters of the whole content (in Chinese version),the result should be 391(including punctuation). For these characters written to a text file,please select the possible file size without any data corrupt.

A、782 bytes in UTF-16 encoding
B、784 bytes in UTF-16 encoding
C、1173 bytes in UTF-8 encoding
D、1176 bytes in UTF-8 encoding
E、None of above

which are the right answers? and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

As Colonel Panic points out, you'll need to do a detailed analysis of each character in the 391 character paragraph to actually work this out. But it looks like your examiner has a really evil sense of humour - all 4 answers are arguably correct, assuming that all chars fit on the BMP and depending on whether BOM's are used or not. Your best bet is to look for an uncommon character which isn't on the BMP which would push both UTF8 and UTF16 to an additional escape sequence, in which case the answer is none of the above.

**In Detail**

[In UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) there will be one character for all ASCII characters (values 0 through 127)

And it seems that MOST 'common' CJK characters use 3 bytes, although the less common CJK characters may need the full 4 bytes to encode.
Now of course it depends on whether your OS wants [Byte Order Markers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark)  or not.

So e.g. if all bytes in the 391 character paragraph are *common* Chinese characters and there are no BOM's, UTF-8 should be 1173 bytes. With BOM's this would be 1176 bytes.

In UTF-16, it seems that most of the common CJK characters are on the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), so would require just 2 bytes to encode each char. i.e. 391 * 2 = 782.

UTF 16 almost always has a 2 byte [Byte Order Marker](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1) (FE FF or FF FE) - i.e. 784 bytes.

FWIW, the 6 characters you provided (兰亭集序行书) are all on the BMP - [check here](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/).

Answer (score 1):

**More information needed**. UTF-8 and UTF-16 (but not UTF-32) are both variable width encodings. In UTF-8 some characters are encoded as a single 8-bit byte (an octet), other characters take as many as four octets.

Comment: From my point of view,since every Chinese character is at least encoded with two bytes,if use UTF-16, should it be 391*2 = 782? and when comes to UTF-8, i totally have no idea how to calculate it.